# Solar panel - blocking diode - DC to DC converter

Tags: solar-cell

I have a solar panel that outputs 21 V. My idea is to connect it to a DC-DV converter and a TP4056 to charge a Li-po battery.

[image]

Just like on this schematic, but first the DC-DC converter so that it can step down to 5 V and then to the TP4056 and then to the rest of the devices like ESP8266/Raspberry Pi.

What I wonder about is: normally you need a blocking diode that you can see on the schematic to block the current flow back from the batteries and thus discharging them (e.g. at night). But having the DC-DC converter first do I still need a blocking diode or will the DC-DC converter already stop the back-current flow?

Comment: The battery charger won't work properly if you're also drawing current from the battery. Rather take power from before the battery charger (taking from the battery when it's dark, of course).

Answer (score 1):

It’s a bad idea .  You want to detect the solarity with a PD then regulate the Vpv down from 83% to 72% of Voc max  with a matched impedance of Vol/Isc which rises as solarity  decreases then use a step up current source that obeys this while limiting the output voltage and cutoff.

This step up current stores energy in V=LdI/dt * t then dumps it faster into the battery in a continuous low ripple at lower voltage. Thus choice of L and f are critical.

A cap across PV stores current also for each cycle in order to keep the PV current constant.

Using two inductors and alternate switching improves efficiency greatly to keep Ipv more constant in Continuous mode.

Comment: "two inductors and alternate switching" sounds genuinely interesting, do you have a link to a description? How does it improve efficiency - because of series resistance of the capacitors?

Comment: Hmm ok if to scratch that idea and start over. There should be a best practice ready made solution on how to use PV in combination with Lipo batteries for supplying output of e.g. 5v/200mA. Are there any?

Comment: Using 3 phase L switching is even better at low ripple current to stay around the narrow triangular peak of MPT for efficiency but sorry no canned IC with this dual mode; input PD controlled Z matching and. Output Cc/Cv/cutoff SMPS control system but there are expensive MPPT unit chargers. Maybe you can invent one?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your diode is backwards, so if you drew the circuit right, you shouldn't see any charging at all. And you'll lose a significant amount of Vf with a 1N4001.  Use a Schottky diode, instead (0.3 Vf, instead of 0.7 V). Otherwise, the circuit looks fine, assuming the solar panels generate enough voltage and current to overcome the draw of your circuit.

Comment: The final charge phase will be extended with an additional parallel load and the charger will make false assumptions about the cell. This appears to work for a while, but the cell might be degraded soon.